# Can't see a map or select pokémon

Tags: pokemon-go

I have problem with *Pokémon Go*. When I meet with professor he wants from me to select one of those three pokémon but I can't select any of them. Nothing happens when I click any of them. Also my map is blue.

When I launch this game I get "GPS signal not found" but I enabled GPS, disabled mock mode, enabled high traffic and same problem happens..

[image: screen]

Comment: By high traffic do you also also mean high accuracy? Correct me if I'm wrong but it also seems like your GPS location isn't turned on?

Comment: Yes high accuracy. But you can see it's near wifi and that it is turned on but it's gray and i don't know why.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your device? It seems like your GPS location is on but it's simply not getting your location.

Comment: Yep i tried this too..

Comment: Any way to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Test to see if google maps works and can get your location.

If it can get your location then perhaps somehow the app does not have permission to access your phone's GPS location? Since you've turned off mock locations and have high accuracy turned on I can't really see any other reason, so perhaps reinstalling the app would help.

If your google maps also can't get your location then it probably means you're simply not getting GPS signal wherever you're and I suggest trying a different place.

Comment: Yes it works perfectly. You can see it.http://bit.ly/29GUdue

Comment: Are you at a place where pokemon go has been released? Also try using your 3G/4G data rather than wifi and see if that helps.

Comment: No it's not been officialy released in my country but for my other friends it works.

Comment: Have you tried a different location/using your mobile data?

Comment: Well this is the problem because i don't have mobile data bought.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you're able to do then :/
Maybe try a different wifi signal?

Comment: Then i don't know why this doesn't work for my phone :/...

Comment: Solution : Update Google Maps and Google Games.